# In C++, how to delete a pointer of a structure outside the function where it was allocated?

Tags: c++

```
structure struct_ppl{
    char* name;
    int age;
}people;

void incription(struct_ppl* ppl)
{
    ppl->name = new char[10];
    ...//some codes, but we do not delete ppl->name
}
int main()
{
    people new_ppl;
    inscription(&new_ppl);

    ... //some codes    

    1. delete(&new_ppl.name);
    2. delete(new_ppl.name);
}
```

In the code above, which one is correct to delete the pointer, 1. or 2.? or neither of them?
thanks for advance

Comment: add a destructor to struct_ppl. Use std::string for name. Lots of options. std::unique_ptr is also one of them.

Comment: With that said, unless you have very explicit requirements to use `char*` and doing your own memory allocations, don't use them. Use `std::string` for all your strings.

Comment: Shouldn't `new[]` be paired with `delete[]`, which makes it a third option, `delete[] new_ppl.name`?

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: In modern C++ you should not use explicit `new` and `delete`. In your case you should use `std::string` or `std::array` or `std::vector`. In other cases use `std:::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`. This way resource management will become automatic.

Comment: You delete the pointer, not the address of the pointer. So option 2 is correct, except that you must use `delete[]` not `delete` because you used `new[]` not `new`.

Comment: `delete p` and `delete [] p` destroy and deallocate the object that `p` points to.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::string and member functions

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct person_t // your struct only holds data for ONE person so ...
{
    std::string name;
    int age;

    ~person_t()
    {
        // no need free memory explicitly, std::string's destructor will do that.
    }

    //make functions that act on data of a struct a member function
    void inscription()
    {
        name = "?";
    }
};


int main()
{
    person_t person;
    person.inscription();

    std::cout << person.name;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> which one is correct to delete the pointer, 1. or 2.? or neither of
> them?

Neither, you **should** and **must** use `delete[]` when allocating from `new[]`.

Be aware that the code has a potential for memory leak, calling `void incription(struct_ppl* ppl)` would leak `char* name` when called more than once without "deallocating" and destroying the previously allocated `char* name`.

Answer (score 0):

> which one is correct to delete the pointer, 1. or 2.? or neither of them?

Neither of them since you're using the `new[]` form to allocate the memory dynamically, you **must** use the corresponding deallocation function of the form `delete[]`.